# Birthdays don't "stick" in Mac Outlook 2011 contacts

Tags: macos, contacts, microsoft-outlook-2011

I can create a birthday for a contact by adding it to the personal section, and that automatically generates an age, but when I save the change, then leave and come back to the same contact, the age is still there but the birthday is not.  Wassup?